# Problem with undefined control sequence in expl3-code.tex file

Tags: expl3, cv

I wanted to create CV with the template by Christophe Roger ( https://github.com/darwiin/awesome-neue-latex-cv) and I am having a very hard time trying to figure out what does the following error mean:

[image]

It comes from file expl3-code.tex but honestly - since the template is not mine - I do not even know when and where this file is called and what it is supposed to be. And I have absolutely no idea what is `\__tl_tmp:w \c__tl_i_ogonek_tl  { 012F }` supposed to do and why it is undefined in the file...

I am using TeX Live 2018 and I am trying to compile the file with LuaLaTeX, which is (as I understood), suggested by the author of the package.

Any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: As requested, the 'head' of log file up to the moment when the error occurs for the firs time is

```
    This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)  (format=lualatex 2018.5.26)  26 MAY 2018 21:00
 restricted system commands enabled.
**cv.tex
(./cv.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 4
[\directlua]:1: module 'luaotfload-main' not found:
    no field package.preload['luaotfload-main']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luaotfload-main'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luaotfload-main'
Error in luaotfload: reverting to OT1 (./yaac-another-awesome-cv.cls
Document Class: yaac-another-awesome-cv 2018/03/26 v1.9.0 'YAAC: Another Awesome
 CV' Class
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+lmr on input line 54.

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd
File: ot1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/05/10 3.21 The Babel package

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/05/10 3.21 Babel switching mechanism
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def
\l@dumylang=\language2
Package babel Info: Non-standard hyphenation setup on input line 113.
\l@nohyphenation=\language3
\l@ukenglish=\language4
\l@usenglishmax=\language5
\l@polish=\language6
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-polish/polish.ldf
Language: polish 2005/03/31 v1.2l Polish support from the babel system

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2018/05/10 3.21 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen103

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def))
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 83.
\pl@left=\dimen104
\pl@down=\dimen105
\pl@right=\dimen106
\pl@temp=\dimen107

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-pl.tex
UTF-8 Polish hyphenation patterns
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-pl.tex))))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luainputenc/luainputenc.sty
Package: luainputenc 2010/11/19 v0.973 inputenc package for LuaTeX

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
Package: luatexbase 2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty
Package: ctablestack 2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
\@catcodetablestackcnt=\count89
)
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable5
\CatcodeTableExpl=\catcodetable6
)
Lua module: luainputenc 2010/05/10 0.97 Lua simple inputenc package.
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luainputenc/lutf8.def
File: lutf8.def 2010/05/10 v0.97 UTF-8 support for luainputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encodingT1

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encodingOT1

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encodingOMS

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
)
Now handling font encoding TU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding TU
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2018-05-13 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2018-05-13 L3 programming layer (code)
\ucharcat@table=\catcodetable7
\c_max_int=\count90
\l_tmpa_int=\count91
\l_tmpb_int=\count92
\g_tmpa_int=\count93
\g_tmpb_int=\count94
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count95
\c_log_iow=\count96
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count97
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count98
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count99
\l__iow_indent_int=\count100
\c_zero_dim=\dimen108
\c_max_dim=\dimen109
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen110
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen111
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen112
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen113
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count101
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count102
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen114
\g__intarray_font_int=\count103
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count110
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count111
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count112
\g__fp_array_int=\count113
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count114
\l__sort_length_int=\count115
\l__sort_min_int=\count116
\l__sort_top_int=\count117
\l__sort_max_int=\count118
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count119
\l__sort_block_int=\count120
\l__sort_begin_int=\count121
\l__sort_end_int=\count122
\l__sort_A_int=\count123
\l__sort_B_int=\count124
\l__sort_C_int=\count125
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count126
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count127
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count128
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count129
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count130
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count131
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count132
\l__regex_balance_int=\count133
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count134
\l__regex_mode_int=\count135
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count136
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count137
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count138
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count139
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count140
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count141
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count142
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count143
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count144
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count145
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count146
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count147
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count148
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count149
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count150
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count151
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count152
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count153
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count154
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count155
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count156
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count157
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count158
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count159
\l__regex_step_int=\count160
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count161
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count162
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count163
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count164
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count165
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count166
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count167
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count168
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen117
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen118
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen123
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen129
\c_empty_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen132
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen133
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen134
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen135
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen136
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen137
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen138
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen139
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count169
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count170

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.26054   \__tl_tmp:w \c__tl_i_ogonek_tl  { 012F }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \let \@err@               ...
l.26054   \__tl_tmp:w \c__tl_i_ogonek_tl  { 012F }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: We'll need to see the first error in the raw log: I have a feeling this is a 'passing' issue that is now fixed, but from the editor view of the log it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Already `module 'luaotfload-main' not found` looks very suspicious.

Comment: @egreg - seems like lack of this file was most probably the reason for the error, because after installing `luaotfload` via `tlmgr` file compiled properly. Thanks for this advice! Case closed, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The key is

```
[\directlua]:1: module 'luaotfload-main' not found:
    no field package.preload['luaotfload-main']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luaotfload-main'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luaotfload-main'
Error in luaotfload: reverting to OT1
```

This means an incorrect installation of `luaotfload`. Fix it.